# Cannot split word into individual letters in a memo

Tags: loops, delphi, delphi-2010

```
unit frmDisplaySentence_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TfrmDispOneChar = class(TForm)
    edtCode: TEdit;
    btnDisplay: TButton;
    lblMsg: TLabel;
    memOutput: TMemo;
    procedure btnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmDispOneChar: TfrmDispOneChar;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmDispOneChar.btnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    K, iLength : integer;
    cOne : char;
    sCode : string;
begin
    sCode := edtCode.Text;
    iLength := Length(sCode);
    for K := 1 to iLength do
        cOne := sCode[K];
        memOutput.Lines.Add(cOne);

end;
```

---

This is my code to split a word into it's individual letters in an memo, each in separate lines.

My code only returns the last letter of the word. I feel this is very close but I do not know how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using the debugger may help you figure out this kind of problem yourself next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi is not like ie Python where whitespace is significant and defines block. In Delphi you have to use `begin` and `end` to mark the block, in this case your for loop:

```
procedure TfrmDispOneChar.btnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    K, iLength : integer;
    cOne : char;
    sCode : string;
begin
    sCode := edtCode.Text;
    iLength := Length(sCode);
    for K := 1 to iLength do begin
        cOne := sCode[K];
        memOutput.Lines.Add(cOne);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: couldn't believe it was that easy *facepalm* thanks though